# Why doesn't fixed point iteration for $2x^3-4x^2+x+1$ work for the initial value of 2?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

A fixed point iteration formula for $2x^3-4x^2+x+1=0$ can be derived:
$$x_{r+1}=4x_r^2-2x_r^3-1$$

Starting with the initial value of 2:

$$x_0=2$$
$$x_1=-1$$
$$x_2=5$$
$$x_3=-151$$
$$x_4=6977105$$

Instead of converging to the root the sequence diverges.

However, the formula seems to work for 1.5.

[image: Worked solution]

Why does the sequence converge for 1.5 but diverge for 2?

Comment: More or less, the necessary condition for convergence is that the derivate is smaller than $1$ between the guess and the root we want to find. To achieve this, it is often necessary to have a start value near enough to the desired root. We have similar situations also in other methods , like the Newton method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Observe from graph that if you will start from $x_0=2$, $4x^2-2x^3-1|_{x=2}<0$ and for all other iteration you can observe that you will go down and down on the graph of $4x^2-2x^3-1$. Hence iteration scheme will diverge.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x, h(x)) = 0 $ then $x_{r+1} = g(x_r)$ will be the iterative equation *iff* the  $|g'(x)| \in (0, 1) \forall x\in \text{domain}$ as commented by @Peter which in the above function for $2x^3−4x^2+x+1=0$ your iterative equation $g(x) = 4x^2_r−2x^3_r−1$ which is giving you answer for $x = 1.5$ but if I choose $f(x) = 2x^3 - 4x^2 + x + 1 = 0$ so if I add x to both sides and $x = 2x^3 - 4x^2 + 2x + 1  = g(x)$ this also diverges for $x = 1.5 $[image: images] so basically it's the choice of your function that decides the fate of $x$ whether it'll be destined to the root or will be thrown away from the roots.

Comment: This may not answer your question but all that I wanted to say is that its choice of function $x =g(x)$