# How can I use fixed point iteration for $2x^3-4x^2+x+1=0$ to find the negative root?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

How can I use fixed point iteration for $2x^3-4x^2+x+1=0$ to find the negative root?
[image]
The  worked solution to the question uses the following iterative formula, it apparently finds a solution at -0.3660 (4sf) but I am unable to retrieve this result:
$$x_{r+1}=\sqrt{\frac{2x_r^3+x_r+1}{4}}$$
[image: -0.3660 to 4sf after 18 iterations which isn't displayed]

I can find positive roots such as 1 and 1.366(4sf) [[link]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370574/why-doesnt-fixed-point-iteration-for-2x3-4x2x1-work-for-the-initial-value), but I am unable to find the negative root for the function using fixed point iteration. I have tried $x_0=-0.5$ which eventually finds the root at $1$. $x_0=-1$ and below seems to result in the square root of a negative number that does not have a real solution.

Comment: Bisection in $\displaystyle\left[-1,0\right]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (real) graph of $\sqrt{\frac{2x^3+x+1}4}$ does not intersect that of $x$ when $x<0$, but that of $-\sqrt{\frac{2x^3+x+1}4}$ (the negative) does. Try iterating with this negated function from $x=-0.5$.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it that the function has to be negated to find the negative root?

Answer (score 0):

The Newton-Rapson approach works pretty fine:

[image]